# HTML doesn't display photos localy

Tags: html, css, image

I am having problem with my HTML... I try to load images from my local drive, path to folder is good for sure because when i ctrl + click it, it opens image and when i open my page with live server or host it somewhere images load, but when i load it by opening index.html, no picture are shown.

From live server

[image: From live server]

By opening index.html

[image: By opening index.html]

```
<img src="/img/special.png" alt=" ">
 background-image: url(/img/apartments.png);
```

I use images with one of these 2 lines of code, and it doesn't load tham..

Comment: What does your directory structure look like on your local machine? Try removing the trailing slash if it's not in the root of your local server.

Comment: Post your directory structure, please ?

Comment: by opening index.html, i assume you are doing it locally? put the index.html into a folder. Then inside the folder create another folder named `img`. So now your main folder should have index.html and img folder. Inside ur img folder, put your images.

Comment: The difference between your local machine and the server is that the server is hosting it. So if you host a server using any simple http server you machine would behave like the server only. One way is using Python https://2ality.com/2014/06/simple-http-server.html

Comment: I found a fix.... It should go ./img, and if i am using it from css (because its in style directory) than it should go ../img. Thanks all for assistance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix.... It should go ./img , and if i am using it from css (because its in style directory) than it should go ../img. Thanks all for assistance... and hopefully someone find this usefull one day

Answer (score 0):

use `<img src="~/img/special.png" alt=" ">`